# How to do group by according to sorted value in Pandas, Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data set like

```
       Type1 Value
        A    1
        B    6
        C    4
        A    3
        C    1
        B    2
```

For each element in Type1, I want it to sum over Value, and then display it in sorted order.

I want my result like,

```
       Type1 Value
        A    4
        C    5
        B    8
```

Comment: Aside: you're going to want to read through the documentation. This is covered in the section on the [split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) pattern, which is the first google result for "pandas group by".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B'], [1, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2]], index=['Type1', 'Value']).T

df2 = df.groupby('Type1').sum()
```

This gives:

```
       Value
Type1       
A          4
B          8
C          5
```

If this isn't sorted, you can do `df2.sort_index(inplace=True)`.

If you want to turn `Type1` back into a column, you can do `df3 = df2.reset_index()`.

Comment: A slight change to my question, is it possible to normalize this sort in any way? Like, if A comes 4 times, I want it to be sum()/(no. of occurence of A) and then sort using this value. How do I do this?

Comment: That would just be the mean.  So replace `sum` with `mean`.